# Runtime-error Object variable or with variable not set

Tags: object, variables, runtime-error

I am getting "run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" on the following code and can't seem to work out what is wrong.

I have set the following variables:

```
Dim EngineAncillariesProjectsVBAList As Range
Dim EngineAncillariesProjectsLastRow As Long
Dim ProjectList As Range
```

Which are defined by:

```
EngineAncillariesProjectsLastRow = Worksheets("VBA_Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

Set EngineAncillariesProjectsVBAList = Worksheets("VBA_Data").Range("H2:H" & EngineAncillariesProjectsLastRow)
```

The error is coming at the following stage, see below. On Debug it is saying that ProjectList = Nothing

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Engine Ancillaries" Then ProjectList = EngineAncillariesProjectsVBAList
```

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: Sorry Vadim, I don;t understand the question?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please edit your question and add it to question tags